# limit a query result to a specific row

Tags: php, mysql

Assume I get an array from mysql in php that contains the following items:

> A, B, B, B

I do a foreach on the array and examine each item. For each item I run a query that returns another value. On the first item I have no problem since the following query returns just one item:

```
SELECT id, id_ogg FROM rischiatura WHERE id_ruolo = 'RU010000003' AND id_ndg = '$ndg'
```

where the $ndg value is taken from the array. So in the first run I get id_ndg = 'A'.

In the other runs the query returns each time three results (it is ok -  three same items in the array = three rows returned from this query). 
My issue is:
**inside the foreach loop how to run this query limiting the result to the first returned row the first time, the second in the second run and the third in the third run?**

The starting point is:

```
foreach($items as $ndg){
    SELECT id, id_ogg FROM rischiatura WHERE id_ruolo = 'RU010000003' AND id_ndg = '$ndg';
}
```

I am looking for some code that will work both with A that is a single item and for B that will return each time one of the three results.

Comment: I'm unable to understand your question statement. What do you actually want to do ?

Comment: In my foreach I run the query with id_ndg = 'B' three times and each time I get three results. I want the query to return: the first time the first result, the second time the second and the third the third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ... WHERE ... LIMIT 0, 1
SELECT ... WHERE ... LIMIT 1, 1
SELECT ... WHERE ... LIMIT 2, 1
```

The arguments to [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html#idm139780785812608) are the starting offset (optional) and the number of rows to return. But if it were me I would detect duplication in the first query's results, and just process three rows from one follow-up query:

```
# (Remove duplicates from $items, then ...)
foreach($items as $ndg){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, id_ogg FROM rischiatura 
                                 WHERE id_ruolo = 'RU010000003' AND id_ndg = '$ndg'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
         # Process each result row: no duplication
    }
```

}

Of course you can use `mysqli` or `PDO` the same way; this is for illustration (and *not* an endorsement of the `mysql_*` API).

Comment: I was working on this too. Question: isn't the offset starting from 0?

Comment: You might want to add a `ORDER BY` clause here otherwise you might get unexpected results.

Comment: Good point... normally the order is consistent, but I don't believe SQL guarantees that.

Comment: @mrun you say that running the same query three times may lead mysql to order the results in different ways? I thought it would always be the same!

Comment: Oops, thank you @Lelio! Rows are numbered from 1, but the first argument is the offset, not the starting row.

Comment: "_I would detect duplication in the first query's results, and just process three rows from one follow-up query._" I would do too but this requirement comes after the db structure has been designed and the db is up and running. Trying to implement this would require a strong db redesign.

Comment: @Lelio, you misunderstand me: No changes to the database are involved. Your first results array contains three copies of `B`. Nobody forces you to issue three requests with `id_ngd = 'B'`. Remove duplicates from this array, and you can forget about `LIMIT` **and**  save yourself a lot of follow-up queries.

Comment: @LelioFaieta, yes exactly. You can check [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql) out for more detailed explanation.

Comment: @alexis i have to build a table with all the info at foreach level. One row for array item. One cell for each row will be filled by the limited query. If I follow your logic I have to follow a much different approach

Comment: Actually it's pretty trivial: Replace your single loop with two nested loops. Hold on...

Answer (score 0):

If to solve just as you mentioned:

```
<?php
$items = array('A', 'B', 'B', 'B');
$unique = array_count_values($items);
foreach ($unique as $key => $value){
    for($i = 0; $i < $value; $i++){
        echo "SELECT * FROM `bla_bla` WHERE `bla` = '$key' LIMIT $i, 1\n";
    }
}
?>
```

gives

```
SELECT * FROM `bla_bla` WHERE `bla` = 'A' LIMIT 0, 1
SELECT * FROM `bla_bla` WHERE `bla` = 'B' LIMIT 0, 1
SELECT * FROM `bla_bla` WHERE `bla` = 'B' LIMIT 1, 1
SELECT * FROM `bla_bla` WHERE `bla` = 'B' LIMIT 2, 1
```

Comment: but what would be your inteneded logics if `$items = array('A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A')` what do you do if several repetitions are split among the array?